# 'View duplicate questions' button shows more than just duplicates

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, vote-to-delete, linked-questions

When voting to delete a question that has linked duplicates, a dialogue appears:

> [image: screenshot of the dialogue]

The 'View duplicate questions' button points to the 'Linked Questions' page, which contains more than just questions closed as a duplicate.

<del>Shouldn't it point to a page that lists duplicates exclusively?</del> As @bluefeet points out in the comments, this is intentional. Can the wording be changed to clarify this?

Comment: Another question, maybe someone can point out an existing discussion about this: why can closed off-topic questions be the target of a 'duplicate' close vote?

Comment: Do you have an example of a question that shows more than just duplicates?

Comment: @bluefeet http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937797/best-c-sharp-api-to-create-pdf

Comment: @Stijn: Why shouldn't "Off-topic" questions be valid dupe targets?

Comment: @Cerbrus Because it makes it more difficult to delete bad questions.

Comment: If it's that bad that is has to be deleted, it shouldn't have been used as dupe target in the first place. But I can imagine there are off-topic questions that don't necessarily need to be deleted.

Comment: It's showing any post that links to it. If that main post is deleted, then all those internal site links would also break. I wouldn't call this a bug, since we're preventing breaking any link to the post - duplicate or not.  If anything, the wording should be clarified a bit.

Comment: @bluefeet That's fine too, I've updated the question.

Comment: @bluefeet What do we do in a case like this when comments need to be deleted?  Flag for a mod?

Comment: @NathanOliver On comments I'd probably say use an other comment flag explaining what's up.